# Is OData URI parsing grammar well defined for resource paths?

Tags: parsing, odata

According to the [OData URL grammar](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt) the `serviceRoot` production of

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')/FirstName
```

results in

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')/
```

basically because it accepts `"("` and `")"` (via the productions `segment-nz`, `sub-delims` and `other-delims`).

However, to me, that should be part of the resource path. Specifically, the resource path of the previous URL should be:

```
People('russellwhyte')
```

I get what I expect by removing `other-delims` from the `segment-nz` (referenced from `serviceRoot`). But this change means altering the grammar provided by OData.

Has anybody encoutered this issue and how they have resolved it?